# Spatio-temporal statistical analysis

Tags: spatial-statistics, software-recommendations, matlab, spatio-temporal-data

I need to perform an anomaly analysis in both space and time. I have 4 data parameters: latitude, longitude, time and temperature. What I’m trying to do is to find temperature anomalies that are present at different locations and time. Are there any readily available methods in **MATLAB** or commercial solutions that could do such Space-time analysis? I noticed that the software **SaTScan** does Space-Time analysis, but it is mostly implemented on medical related fields. Would it be possible to use it here?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a complex statistical analysis question due to the auto-correlation, both in space and time. You are having a tool-driven point of view to your problem, however without a concrete understanding of space, time and statistical approaches to handle them, you won't get almost anywhere.

One way handle this problem is the ARIMA model. Another is state-space-models (SSMs).

If R (statistical programming software) is an option for your, there are user-contributed packages that can get you on the track. see [State Space Models in R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v041i04/v41i04.pdf) paper .

I am not aware of any MATLAB library for SSMs (google it yourself)